# Get MediaPlayer & AudioManager to play through earpiece instead of speaker?

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming, android-audiomanager

Hey I'm trying to play a R.raw file thru my earpiece instead of the main phone speaker on my app but everyhting I throw at it isn't working. WIht my current code... it just plays very light static through the earpiece and not the R.raw I want.

Here is my code below and I set it in the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>`

```
 AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 

        MediaPlayer tellSecret = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.secret);
    tellSecret.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
    tellSecret.start();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I notice you didn't accept the answer given, and I would love to know what you did do as I'm trying to do, well the opposite actually! - I want the sound to always use the loudspeaker :)

Comment: @noelicus : Did you find a solution to your problem finally? I am trying to do what you did, but not able to find a solution. I asked a huge series of questions about work-arounds(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965530/how-to-mute-audio-in-headset-but-let-it-play-on-speaker-programmatically), but I am unable to find it. Please let me know.

Comment: Hi @Gautham, yes I did - I've answered your question from your link now. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Audio Manager and the Media Player modes to be AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC.

Comment: Or just make sure that both your AudioManager and the MediaPlayer are in the same mode.

Answer (score 1):

do not use 'create' api for media player, instead use 'setDataSource' and 'prepare' apis seperately. Also call 'setAudioStreamType' api on mediaplayer instance with STREAM_VOICE_CALL before calling 'setDataSource'.

In the end after starting media player,
call setSpeakerphoneOn(false) on audio manager.