# How to mute audio in headset but let it play on speaker programmatically?

Tags: android, soundpool, android-audiomanager, headset, speakerphone

I am searching a work-around for my problem specified in this question:

[How to disable the wired headset programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949769/how-to-disable-the-wired-headset-programmatically-in-java)

As mentioned there, I am getting audio in both my speakers and headphones.

Can someone please tell me how to **mute** the audio in the headset **programmatically**, while letting it play **undiminished** on speaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

And then play the sound through the `AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM` stream.

When the sound's finished playing be sure to return the audio manager to its previous state or it'll stay on loudspeaker!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Couple of questions though. How did you set it back to normal? *And then play the sound through the AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM stream.*- What specific command did you use for this?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks a ton for the answer :) Will contact you if any further queries from this post. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

> AudioManager mAudioMgr =
>   (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
>   mAudioMgr.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
>   mAudioMgr.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

Comment: For me, this did work. I also had to add a permission in the manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />`