# what code can disable headphone jack for an android(4.4) device

Tags: android, audio, headphones

Im trying to build an app that can enable or disable the headphone jack on my Android 4.4 device . Once disabled nothing should be able to take control or activate it, even calling. I can root the device for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this previous answer: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965530/how-to-mute-audio-in-headset-but-let-it-play-on-speaker-programmatically)

Comment: @EdGeorge: It sounds to me like the OP wants to do this system-wide, i.e. prevent the audio from all apps to be routed to the 3.5mm jack. The `setMode/setSpeakerPhone` method doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: Yup, I am trying to do it system wide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written here: [How to mute audio in headset but let it play on speaker programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965530/how-to-mute-audio-in-headset-but-let-it-play-on-speaker-programmatically/20982880#20982880)

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

And then play the sound through the AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM stream.

When the sound's finished playing be sure to return the audio manager to its previous state or it'll stay on loudspeaker.

Comment: I'll test and see if I can use this as a work around. I would like to point out that , I am not trying to play my own sound, I am trying to disable system from using headphone jack.