# Disable headset on Android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, headset

manager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                 manager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);How to disable a headset in Android that I could handle a pressing of button on the headset.

When I call anybody voice transfers to headset but I want that voice transfer to internal dynamic (as usual). 
 I have found application in play market iKey https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ligq.ikey that implements it. But I couldn't explain how they do this.

I tried such way but voice is in speaker but I want in internal dynamic(as usual call).

```
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager).
         getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    manager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: check it, may be helpful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965530/how-to-mute-audio-in-headset-but-let-it-play-on-speaker-programmatically

Comment: I have tried it, above link enable external dynamic, but I want enable  internal microphone